# Cloning/Converting Local Perforce Workspace to Mercurial Repo

Tags: mercurial, perforce

I'm new to Perforce and Mercurial, so bear with me.  I would like to use Mercurial to interface with Perforce in the following way:

I check-out a local Perforce workspace using the P4V client.  I then clone a Mercurial repo of that workspace, and use this cloned repo for all my work.  When I need updated files, I would first update the local Perforce workspace, and then have the Mercurial repo pull from that.  When I'm ready to commit, I push my changes to the local Perforce workspace.  Then I use the P4V client to commit my changes in the Perforce workspace to the Perforce depot.  Essentially, the local Perforce workspace is a proxy for the Perforce repot.

The reason behind this set-up (versus the common scenario of directly pulling from and pushing to the Perforce repot) is that there is some configuration I need to do via the P4V client (such as mapping/renaming files and directories).

I've looked at the convert and perfarce extensions, but I'm not quite sure they do what I want.  They seem to do a one-time conversion, and then thereafter they talk directly to the Perforce repot.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert does an incremental conversion, where it will convert only new changes, but it's unidirectional only (perforce -> mercurial).

I've not looked at the perfarce extension, but it's my understanding that's it's built for a bi-directional, continuous process -- you might want to look at it again.

Alternately, the non-extension options on the [Working with Subversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) page in the mercurial wiki, details a process for using Mercurial alongside/atop Subversion w/o them interacting in any way except for the file working directory.  That's probably very similar to what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Perfarce extension should do what you want. I'm also experimenting with a similar setup, and I can pull & push to Perforce quite happily.

I must admit I am having issues with local config files and how they operate in this environment, but there's a couple of other answers here on SO that appear to address this.

I would recommend you give Perfarce a go first, before reverting to anything more manual.